# Is there any way for "position:absolute" div to retain relative width?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Let's say I have two divs, one inside the other, like so:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="outer" style="width:50%">
      <div id="inner" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now, the inner div has a width of 100% of 50% of the screen size, or 50% of the screen size. If I were to change the inner div to position absolute, like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="outer" style="width:50%">
      <div id="inner" style="position:absolute;width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case the inner div takes up 100% of the screen space, because its position is set to absolute.

My question is this: Is there any way to maintain relative width of the inner div while its position is set to absolute?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Add **position:relative** to your outer div.

*update*: It works because positions in `position: absolute` are relative to the first parent that has some positioning (other than static). In this case there was no such container, so it uses the page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was annoying me for about an hour. I'm glad the solution is so simple :)

Comment: OHHH AHHH!!! I spent the last 5 hours trying to fix this damn site I've been working on. Thank you so much for this. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: If your outer div is an `<svg>` and you want to layer text on top of it, you will need to put another outer `<div>` like this and use z-indexing instead with both absolute:
`<div style="{position: relative}">
 <svg style="{position: absolute; z-index: 0}" />
 <div style="{position: absolute; z-index: 100}">This is my Svg label!</div>
</div>` I had this problem, and this solution worked for me! Sadly, `<svg>`'s can't really have children.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  Set outer to position: relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/57673/

```
.outer
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner
{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had an element that had to be `position:absolute` in a project and I found that setting `width` to `max-content` fixed that for me.
It seems to be well supported across modern browsers. Check this link for more info: [Mozilla.org (max-content)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content) .

Comment: You just saved me like 4 hours of debugging, thank you!